# Why is $f(x)=x^2$ a continuous function?

Tags: general-topology

Why is $f(x)=x^2$ a continuous function with respect to the topological definition?

So $f$ is a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ sending each $x$ to $x^2$. Clearly $U=[0,1)$ is an open set in $[0,\infty)$, but $f^{-1}(U)=[0,1)$ is NOT an open set in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Then surely $f$ can't be continuous by the definition of a continuous function in topology?

Comment: We have that $f^{-1}(U) = (-1,1)$ so it is indeed open in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: But surely $f^{-1}(-1)$ is undefined? The inverse function $f^{-1}$ is discontinuous at $0$, otherwise it would not be a function.

Comment: @SidCaroline be careful! You can take the inverse of sets with any function, this will be a set. $f^{-1}(\{-1\})=\emptyset$, perfectly well defined. Not to mention above the inverse image of $U$ was taken, not anything involving -1

Comment: It is continuous, and don't call it Shirley.

Comment: So the union of all $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ where $-1<x<0$, is $\emptyset$, which unioned with $f^{-1}([0,1))$, gives you $f^{-1}(U)=[0,1)$?

Comment: Which real numbers $x$ satisfy $0\le x^2 < 1$? Answer: any $x$ such that $-1 < x < 1$ and no other $x$. Hence $f^{-1}([0,1)) = (-1, 1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f^{-1}[[0,1)] = (-1,1)$ which **is** open as required. No problem.

But a base for $[0,\infty)$ is given by open sets of the form $[0,a) ,a>0$ and $(a,b)$ with $0 < a < b$. The former has inverse image $(-\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{a})$ and the latter $(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b}) \cup (-\sqrt{b}, -\sqrt{a})$ and both are open. It suffices to check the inverse images of basic or subbasic elements for continuity.

Comment: But this does not fully answer the question: why is $f(x) = x^2$ a continuous function? It answers rather: why did Sid Caroline mistakenly believe that $f(x) = x^2$ is not continuous.

Comment: I was confused by the notation $f^{-1}$, since it implies $f^{-1}$ is a function. Maybe it's better to use the word pre-image? Or the set of all $x$ in the domain such that $f(x)\in U$, i.e. $f^{-1}(U)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f(x)\in U\}$.

Comment: Anything that can help you to avoid confusion is good!

Comment: @SidCaroline inverse image or pre-image is a good term.